# how to make authenticated requests to Firebase Realtime Database with api key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

What I want is to perform rest requests to Firebase Realtime Database from my esp8266 with micropython firmware without complex authorization process.
I know that I can turn off authorization at all in the rules but I'd prefer to have at least some basic security.

Can't I just use my `Web API Key` for this purpose?
[image: project settings]

[Here is a doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=0) which tells that there are 2 ways of authentication: oauth2 and generating key manually. Second way seems almost what I need but it requires setting up Admin SDK and as far as I understood still requires regenerating the key from time to time.

So eventually I have no answer to a simple question: **how to authenticate rest requests to the *Firebase Realtime Database* in the most simple way?**

Answer (score 3):

The same page you linked to contains a section on [using legacy tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=0#legacy_tokens) (also known as "database secrets" in the past). While those are not recommended anymore, they continue to work and are as simply as adding the (non-dynamic) database secret to your URLs.

I suggest you read the [links at the bottom of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=0#legacy_tokens). But I **do** recommend that you switch to using the OAuth or ID Token flows as those are much more secure.

Comment: Seems that this option isn't simple enough.. Documentation points to this library: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-python and it uses base64 which is not present in the firmware. So I tried to use this version: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micropython/micropython-lib/master/base64/base64.py  
After that I get the next error each time I run the project:
`File firebase_token_generator.py, line 6, in <module> MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 272 bytes` 
6th line is `from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode`

Comment: In other words: I need another solution such as just providing api key. Anyway, thanks for your answer.